# Принципы ООП. Интерфейс

Tags: c++, ооп, интерфейс

Пишу класс для работы с матрицами. Указатель и кол-во строк и столбцов сокрыто, это понятно. Пришла в голову мысль, что можно для доступа к элементу матрицы возвращать ссылку (m[i][j]), а если пользователь запросит несуществующий элемент, вернуть затычку и сгенерировать исключение. Но у меня сомнения по поводу того, насколько нормальна такая практика? У кого есть опыт работы с ООП, хочется услышать ваше мнение.

Для наглядности, по моей задумке можно будет делать так `mtrx.get(i,j) = value`.

Comment: вернуть исключение это нормально

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, я про вернуть ссылку.

Comment: Не вижу никаких проблем, например `std::vector::at` как раз это и делает. *"вернуть затычку и сгенерировать исключение"* Нельзя вернуть что-то из функции, если вы выбросили исключение. Так что никакая специальная "затычка" не нужна.

Comment: Если генерировать исключение - то зачем же возвращать затычку? :)

Comment: @Harry, ну, я просто с исключениями ещё не работал, не знаю точно как они работают, только в общих чертах представляю.

Comment: А зачем прятать количество столбцов  и строк? Поступая таким образом вы вынуждаете тащить их количество вместе с вашей матрицей во всем использующем ее коде

Comment: @avp, ну так это логично для ООП. Хочешь узнать кол-во строк или столбцов - используй метод. Данные должны быть сокрыты, за редкими, может быть, исключениями.

Comment: @Πανμέτρονάριστον - если матрица по ходу своей жизни не может менять свои размеры, лучше затолкать эти размеры в public const

Comment: @Πανμέτρονάριστον, догматизм это не самое лучшее для разработки эффективного (и красивого) ПО

Comment: @gbg, может. Она может быть даже "пустой", если не была инициализирована, либо если явно была "удалена" пользователем.

Comment: Плохой дизайн, RAII поломано.

Comment: @gbg, ничего там не поломано. Если так подумать, то string из стандартной библиотеки тоже "поломан".

Comment: @Πανμέτρονάριστον у стринга нет метода "удались", у него есть метод "опустошись". У строки и у матрицы разная семантика - матрица не прирастает строками и столбцами во время своей жизни.

Comment: Вы не осознаете тонкостей - RAII в целом говорит, что у объекта не может быть состояния, когда он не инициализирован - если вы создали экземпляр матрицы, вы сразу создаете его с нужными размерами и (зачастую), содержимым.
Лично я бы послал в помойку любой класс с многоступенчатой инициализацией - негодно это.

Comment: @gbg, инициализировать содержимое матрицы при создании невозможно в принципе, синтаксические правила языка этого не позволяют делать. Разве что по умолчанию, но это бессмысленно. Да, и никто не заставляет пользователя создавать "пустую" матрицу, а затем создавать её, указывая размер. Есть и явный конструктор и конструктор копирования.

Comment: Правильно было бы написать, что незнание вами синтаксических правил языка не позволяет это сделать - есть два варианта создания матрицы нужного вида (и это важно в практике - уж единичная матрица точно актуальна) - либо наделать статических методов и сделать приватный конструктор, который только выделяет ресурсы, либо наделать шаблонных конструкторов на все случаи жизни + к ним типы-тэги.

Comment: @gbg, Т.е. вы хотите сказать, что можно реализовать инициализацию в духе обычного двумерного массива? int array[rows][cols] = {{}{}{}{}{}}; На сколько я знаю, конструктор делают приватным, чтобы его нельзя было вызвать и создать объект (при наследовании). Поэтому я ничего не понял.

Comment: Вам бы на Eigen посмотреть.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Возвращать нужно уметь две ссылки, константную и неконстантную. И да, это правильная практика.

Константая ссылка нужна для того, чтобы вашу матрицу можно было всю делать константой, без нее - не скомпилируется.

Учтите, что стандартная библиотека C++ в операции `[]` не проверяет индексы у контейнеров-массивов, и для снижения `WTF/seс` будет лучше этому правилу следовать - иначе ваш класс матриц будет лютой черепахой, и вызывать у читателя кода справедливое негодование ("какого черта индекс швыряет исключения?!").

Если вы пишете с надеждой написать что-то быстрое (догнать и перегнать `MKL`!), то исключения вам придется вырубить совсем, опциями компилятора.

Comment: Я не планирую использовать operator[](), потому как у меня внутренне матрица - это указатель на указатель на double. Чтобы было быстрее и надёжнее, потом переделаю с использованием new с размещением, потому как если заменить на одномерный динамический массив, то придётся переписывать вообще всё, а кода уже много.

Comment: Массив указателей на строки скорее всего хуже длинного блока - у него хуже с локальностью (а процессор ой как любит локальность), и он жрет лишнюю память под указатели. Так что быстрее и надежнее выделить один огромный кусок. Возможно, стоит сделать это не при помощи new. а используя системный API прилочить этот кусок намертво к физической памяти, чтобы не свапался.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17260533/5533854

Comment: Да, всё верно ты говоришь, под указатели уходит не мало: количество строк помноженное на 8 байт.